# Swift how to send eMail mail in AppDelegate fetch?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, appdelegate, mailcore2

Im totally helpless right now, i'm trying to send an eMail for data upload in an iOS Swift 4 App. I found the Obj-C Mailcore library which works in normal code, for example in a button press callback. But if i'm trying to use the same code in my `AppDelegate` fetch func it doesn't return from the completionHandler.

The Mailcore send operation is async so i used a semaphore wrapper around it, but the completion handler is never called.

**Edit:**

Apparently the code does not work in the button with the Semaphore. Only if i remove the

```
let _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
```

part.

**So is there another way to wait for the completion of the async completionBlock?**

**Yes, look at my answer :-)**

My code:

```
let smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
[...]
let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperation(with: rfc822Data!)
[...]
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
if (sendOperation != nil) {
    print("Starting sendOperation...")
    sendOperation?.start { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            sendingError = true
            print("Error sending email: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully sent email!")
        }
        sendingDone = true
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    let _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
} else {
    print("Cant init sendOperation")
    sendingError = true
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `sendOperation` is not-nil when you call `start` ? Theres nothing special about an object that adopts `UIApplicationDelegate`

Comment: @Warren Burton Im not sure, but i just copy and pasted it from the button code where it worked so i doesnt bothered. I will check this but shouldnt it crash if i call start() on a nil object?

Comment: `sendOperation` appears to be `Optional` from your code. You can see that from `sendOperation?` using optional chaining.

Comment: @Warren Burton Now i see what you mean. I will check if it is nil.

Comment: @WarrenBurton It is not nil, i added a check and start is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution:

**SyncManager.swift**

```
import Foundation

/// A generic Cocoa-Style completion handler
typealias CompletionHandler = (Error?) -> Void

/// Provides syncronous access to results returned by
/// asynchronous processes with completion handlers
class SyncMaker {
    var result: Error? = nil

    /// Generates a synchronous-compliant completion handler
    func completion() -> CompletionHandler{
        return {
            (error: Error?) in

            // Store result, return control
            self.result = error
            CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())
        }
    }

    // Perform task (that must use custom completion handler) and wait
    func run(_ task: @escaping () -> Void) -> Error? {
        task()
        CFRunLoopRun()
        return result
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift** (partly)

```
[...]
let syncMaker = SyncMaker()
let result = syncMaker.run {
    sendOperation?.start(
        syncMaker.completion())
}
if (result != nil) {
    print("Error sending email: \(result)")
} else {
    sendingError = false
    print("Successfully sent email!")
}
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The completion is either coming on the same thread or runs something in that thread.

The normal thing to do is to not wait, but instead do whatever you need to do after it completes in the completion itself.

If you must do it with a semaphore, move the start call to another thread.